# Make uses multiple cores even without -j argument?

Tags: bash, macos, gnu-make

I've noticed on my MacBook Pro (Quad-core) that when I run make, it takes the same amount of time as make -j, and sure enough, Activity Monitor shows all four cores getting high usage. Why is this? Is there some default setting that Apple has? I mean, it would make sense for -j to be the default, but from what I've seen on the web make with no arguments should only be using one thread.

This isn't necessarily a problem, but I'd like to understand the cause nonetheless.

Comment: We may need an actual working example showing this behaviour. There may be some trickery *inside* the makefile (it could call another makefile with the -j flag), or even something to do with the compiler.

Comment: Here is the makefile: https://gist.github.com/michaelsavich/8711e75fc6c770cb550100d94c249c12

Comment: You generally have a default make file config that specifies the default `-j $NUM_CORES` value. I have no clue where it is on a Mac. Generally you do not set a default greater than `1` because most code (even fairly recent code) does not build in parallel unless the code is specifically written to take advantage of compiling in parallel. You may well be using one core for the actual compile, but there will be plenty of work going on in your other cores as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `-j|--jobs` flag specifies/limits the number of commands that can be run simultaneously, not the number of threads to allocate to a single command. Think of this option as concurrency instead of parallelism.

For example, I can specify `--jobs=2` and have both an ES6 transpiler and a SASS preprocessor running in the background, in the same terminal window, watching for any file changes I may make.